# How do I get all public GitHub repo that are PHP using GitHub API?

Tags: php, github, github-api

I found this link that shows me how to get all repositories using GitHub API.

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-repositories

But I am not sure how to find all the repositories that are PHP.

For e.g. this gives us only a select snapshot. https://github.com/trending?l=php

If this is a limit to how many repositories I can find out, I prefer to get at least 500 of the PHP repositories with the most stargazers.

After that, I would like to get a list of the stargazers and contributors of each repository.

How do I accomplish this using the GitHub API?

I am studying the network effects of these repositories so I need the above raw data.

Comment: Don't forget to mark Ivan's answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Search for that. Here's how you can do it using search on github.com (using the [Advanced Search form](https://github.com/search/advanced)):

https://github.com/search?l=PHP&o=desc&q=stars%3A%3E%3D0&s=stars&type=Repositories

And here's the API equivalent (using the [Search API](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories)):

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:php&sort=stars

However, notice that the [Search API returns only the top 1000 results and the total count](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#about-the-search-api). You could get around that restriction by slicing your search API query into multiple calls based on the [time that the repositories were created](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories#created-and-last-updated).

After getting all repositories, you can use the [Starring API](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/) to get a list of stargazers, and the [Contributors API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors) to get the list of contributors.

Also, you might be interested in the (Unofficial) [GitHub Archive project](http://www.githubarchive.org/) which tracks, saves and exposes events from the public GitHub timeline.